# Javascript append colon to numbers of unknown length?

Tags: javascript

I have a number let's say

```
305060
```

And I want to put a `:` at the -2 and -4 spot so I end up with

```
30:50:60
```

And if I entered 5006070 I would end up with `500:60:70`

I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Comment: number is a string right?

Comment: Yes sorry I suppose I didn't make that obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

```
var number = 123456789;
var formatted = number.toString().replace(/^(\d+)(\d{2})(\d{2})/, '$1:$2:$3');
alert(formatted);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/U4J6n/

If `number` is a string, you can remove the `.toString()` method from the code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex that catches the two last groups of two numbers

```
/(\d{2})(\d{2})$/
```

so it's

```
var x = 305060;  
x = x.toString().replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})$/, ":$1:$2"); // 30:50:60

var x2 = 5006070;
x2 = x2.toString().replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})$/, ":$1:$2"); // 500:60:70
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/C73N2/1/)

Comment: this regex is more fool-proof, but I prefer the longer one user3132718 . This because your regex only requires the last 4 numbers to be \d . I tend to always write white-list type code ;) But this is personal

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose n is the length of the string, first you want to take the number from 0 to n-4 then n-4 to n-2 and finally n-2 to n, so simply use one of substring or slice to get the solution.

If you want to use substring then it would be

```
var num="305060";
var length=num.length;
var ans=num.substring(0,length-4)+":"+num.substring(length-4,length-2)+":"+num.substring(length-2,length);
alert(ans);
```

If you want to use slice then

```
var num="305060";
    var length=num.length;
    var ans=num.slice(0,length-4)+":"+num.slice(length-4,length-2)+":"+num.slice(length-2,length);
    alert(ans);
```

substr is another function in javascript which will help you to get the solution

```
var num="305060";
    var length=num.length;
    var ans=num.substr(0,length-4)+":"+num.substr(length-4,2)+":"+num.substr(length-2,2);
    alert(ans);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

Javascript

```
var x = 305060,
    y = x.toString(),
    z = [y.slice(0, -4), y.slice(-4, -2), y.slice(-2)].join(':');

console.log(z);
```

Output

```
30:50:60
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/xMdJ9/)